# packr2: Command not found

Tags: path, command, exec

I'm trying to build a go project.

When I run **make all** command, this error is showing up.

```
lean start
Get packr2
Clean static files
make: packr2: Command not found
make: *** [Makefile:12: clean] Error 127
```

I tried to install packr2 package from https://github.com/gobuffalo/packr still not working.

**Go version -  go1.17.12 linux/amd64**

Comment: "Command not found" means it's not found in the filesystem directories listed in the [`PATH` environment variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)). Hence you should make sure the path to the `packr2` binary ends up listed there.